# Why is "attention payment" incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds

I have been wondering why some people think that "attention payment" is an accepted phrase. The argument is that you "pay attention", therefore you can learn "attention payment". This sounds incorrect, and my original argument was that payment, in this form, is being used like something akin to a gerund. The verb "to pay" is being used as a noun. In the context of paying attention, the use of the verb is colloquial. You don't actually exchange funds -- but the concept is similar, so we use the verb to describe being attentive.

However, whenever the word "payment" is used, it appears to be used **exclusively to describe the exchange of funds**. I am wondering if this is correct, and if so, specifically why "attention payment" is incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of "attention payment".  Can you give some examples of usage that you've seen?  Also, are you referring to usage in a particular region or country - English usage varies wildly across the world.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just heard it online. Specifically, is it incorrect usage? Or is it a regional thing?

Comment: It's the same with "pay respect(s)", but there's no *"respect(s) payment". By contrast, "pay alimony" gives the acceptable "alimony payment". So yes, the word "payment" in that kind of composite does seem to work when something tangible is being 'transferred' but not something abstract.

Comment: @BillJ - I would say that it is because 'alimony' is a *monetary* payment - not merely because it is "tangible".

Comment: It's not clear that it's technically incorrect.  *Payment* means "the act of paying", and there's no reason for that definition to be limited to monetary transactions.  However, the usage is not particularly idiomatic.

Comment: @TrevorD Yes, it does seem that way. Even related items have some indirect monetary value: _Pay a share bonus_ ~ _a share bonus payment_

Comment: Actually, "payment" is not limited to monetary transactions.  Google shows that "payment of respect" is used in published works, though not very often (and you have to wade through a bunch of red herrings to find the few relevant uses).

Comment: Logically equivalent expressions involving words with the same roots are not guaranteed to be interchangeable (or even acceptable). Thus someone preparing a _scheme of work_ would not be referred to (outside humour) as a _schemer_, and not as a _work-schemer_. _Telescoped Street Washing Bars_ are not referred to as _Street Washing Bar Telescopes_. But acceptability shifts; I was surprised to find that 'fund exchanger' is not uncommon. Though 'bromide-taker' thankfully doesn't seem to have caught on.

Comment: Note also that attributive forms and ones using 'of' tend not to be as interchangeable as might be expected (this is true also with genitive 'alternatives'). Many examples are set expressions: The Sanction of the Eiger? The Shrew Taming? The Roman Empire Decline and Fall?  The d'Urbervilles(') Tess? Wrath's Grapes? The Wake of Finnegans? The End of Howards?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: nice point. Was your inclusion of Howards End a subtle test of our literary knowledge (there being no apostrophe in the name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is true that *payment* implies giving in cash or kind only.

Etimologically, and therefore essentially even in contemporary use, *pay* is to sort of "compensate" (cf. *compensation* as syn. of *pay* -- salary).

See *[pay](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=pay)* on etymonline.

2. Use of *pay* in "paying attention" is metaphorical and the phrase is idiomatic.

["Take Our Word for it," Issue 123, page 2](http://www.takeourword.com/TOW123/page2.html):

> Why do we *pay attention, heed, court*, and *respect*?  We also *pay visits* and *compliments*, don't we?  Well, the idea behind all of this payment is one of duty (softened from the "debt" meaning), so that you "owe" someone your attention or respect, or it is your "duty" to visit or compliment someone.  A lot of the "duty" meaning has been lost so that now we say, for example, *pay a visit* to mean simply "visit".  We first find pay used in this sense in the work of Shakespeare …
>   
>  
>   Where I have come, great clerks have purposed
>   To greet me with premeditated welcomes;
>    …
>   And in conclusion dumbly have broke off,
>   Not paying me a welcome.
>   - Shakespeare, *A Midsummer Night's Dream*, 1592

Comment: [He mocked everything that fed the tender soul of Mrs. Quest, who had always needed the comfort of anniversaries, ceremonies, ritual, the proper payment of respect where it was due.](https://books.google.com/books?id=oRY-paRylkwC&pg=PA240&dq=%22payment+of+respect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8-azMmNzMAhWLJCYKHc-hB4oQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22payment%20of%20respect%22&f=false)

Comment: @Kris: I think your second point is the key, i.e. it's a metaphorical usage derived from the sense that attention is *due* or *owed* and must therefore be "paid". If I can say "I paid attention", it's also fine to say "attention was owed, and I made payment" as a dramatic or ironic extension of the metaphor, in which case reference to my "attention payment" would be both logical and (in context) intelligible.

Comment: In the indispensible [Narrative of the campaign of the Indus in Sind and Kaubool in 1838-9, Volume 2
by Richard Hartley Kennedy](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sTgNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22homage+payment%22&source=bl&ots=Tm2Jzj-MXP&sig=VoavMJoLlCVI_9gsRqo8_8IwvOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqzICDv9zMAhVMB8AKHUAoBXgQ6AEIOTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22homage%20payment%22&f=false) is another abstract example: 'I will take this opportunity of reverting to that said " homage-payment,''...' But scare quotes were deemed necessary.

Comment: @Chappo Please note the conjunctive nature: "... is metaphorical **and** the **phrase** is idiomatic" in my observation above. See also the comments of  Edwin Ashworth on this page about the phrase.

Comment: @Kris: My comment was in support of your answer but sought to extend the analysis (as this site encourages us to do). Thanks though for noting your use of **and**, which I hadn't paid attention to (pun intended). I now realise we're *both* wrong. It seems to me that "to pay (attention, heed, respect, etc)" is neither idiomatic *nor* metaphoric; rather, it's a normal use of the word **pay**: "to settle (a debt, obligation, etc.), as by transferring money or goods, *or by doing something*" (Dictionary.com usage 1; my emphasis). But I stand by my tongue-in-cheek argument re "attention payment".

Comment: @Chappo There was no critique of your comment, only an extension of the analysis. Good Luck.